# Bookmark two consecutive lines that second line include only a date

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a list like following:

```
hrthrhthrht
bntyjhytjtyj
8,083,344
Mar1996
tggrgge
```

Now I need a notepad++ regex that bookmark two following lines:

```
8,083,344
Mar1996
```

this mean two consecutive lines that first line start with a digit and second line include only a date or following regex:

```
\b(?:Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)\d{4}\b
```

I tried following regular expressions but not worked for me:

```
^[^\d\r\n]*(?:\D*(?:Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)\d{4})[^\d\r\n]*$

^[^\d\r\n]*(?:\D*(?:Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)\d{4})[^\d\r\n]*\R[^\d\r\n]*(?:\D*(?:Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)\d{4})[^\d\r\n]*$

^[^\d\r\n]*(?:\D*(?:Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)\d{4})[^\d\r\n]*\R[^\d\r\n]*(?:\D*(?:Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)\d{4})[^\d\r\n]*$

^[^\d\r\n].*\R\b(?:Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)\d{4}\b.*$

^[^\d\r\n].*\R^[^\d\r\n].*\b(?:Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)\d{4}\b.*$

^[^\d\r\n].*\R[^\d\r\n].*\b(?:Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)\d{4}\b.*$

^[^\d\r\n].*\R^[^\d\r\n].*\b(?:Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)\d{4}\b

^[^\d\r\n].*\R[^\d\r\n].*(?:Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)\d{4}\b
```

where is problem?
**note that first line should start with a digit.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this regex to match 2 consecutive lines as desired:

```bash
^\d+(?:,\d+)*\r?\n[^\d\r\n]*(?:Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)\d{4}[^\d\r\n]*$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/xrzbE8/2)

**RegEx Details:**

- `^`: Line Start
- `\d+(?:,\d+)*`: Match 1+ digits then match 0 or more sets of comma followed by 1+ digits
- `\r?\n`: Match a line break
- `[^\d\r\n]*`: Match 0 or more of any character that are not a digit and not a line break
- `(?:Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)`: Match month string
- `\d{4}`: Match 4 digits
- `[^\d\r\n]*`: Match 0 or more of any character that are not a digit and not a line break
- `$`: Line End